# jenkinsfile docker agent get access to private repositories & composer

Tags: php, docker, jenkins, ssh, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I'm trying to use a declarative pipline in the Jenkinsfile to build my php app. My jenkins is running in a docker container, as I want to use this server for other services as well.

My issue is now, that I have to install also private packages from bitbucket over public key authentication with composer. For composer I'm using the docker container from official composer on docker hub.

This is my Jenkinsfile:

```
pipeline {
    environment {
        BUILD_VERSION = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat('yyyyMMddHHmmss').format(new Date())
    }

    options {
        buildDiscarder(logRotator(numToKeepStr: '3'))
    }

    agent any

    stages {

        stage('composer install') {
            agent {
                docker {
                    image 'composer:latest'
                    args "--volume /tmp:/app --volume /etc/passwd:/etc/passwd:ro --volume /etc/group:/etc/group:ro -u 1000"
                }
            }

            steps {
                sshagent(credentials: ['jenkins_ssh_key']){
                    sh 'composer install -d /app'
                }
            }

            post {
                success {
                    echo 'Composer compiled successfully :)'
                }

                failure {
                    echo 'Composer throw an error :('
                }
            }
        }
    }

    post {
        always {
            echo 'Cleaning up'
            deleteDir() /* clean up our workspace */
        }
        success {
            echo 'Build successful finished :)'
        }
        failure {
            echo '[FAILURE] Build was not successful :('
        }
    }
}
```

If I'm using `sh 'composer install'` within `sshagent(...){...}`, like in my file above, it fails with the information that no composer.json was found.

If I'm using `sh 'composer install'` without the sshagent, composer runs like expected, but fails for private repositories.

Hope anyone can help me to solve this issue.

Thank you

Comment: add pwd && composer install with ssh-agent and see which directory the command runs in